# Circuitry with bistable Flip-Flop

Tags: flipflop

I am trying to build a logic in hardware where a pulse will define the state of two output lines.

I believe it should be possible to build this with two or three bistable flipflops.

There would be 3 states:

state A:  output1: 1(or 0), output2: 1(or 0)

state B:  output1: 1 (or 0) , output2: 0 (or 1)

state C:  output1: 0 (or 1) , output2: 1 (or 0)

Basically, put pushing a switch (pull to ground), I would like after each pulse go throught the states:

A => B => A => C => A => B => A  => etc.

Basically toggling between state B and C but always with a state A "in between".

Note that the output = 1 means rather "pull to GND" and output = 0 means "float"

(the outputs are used as inputs for another logic circuitry).

I would try to build this  based on this product:

https://www.amazon.de/-/en/NNGUBIU-IO25A01-Flip-Flop-Bistable-Locking/dp/B07K861TBT

I believe it could be used to mimick a T flipflop.

[image]

However, struggle to get the logic implemented with the desired output.

Any feedback/help welcome.

If not possible, I may go for an ESP32 to implement the logic in code.

Thanks,
br, Koen.

Comment: Relays required? (sounds like two relays are required, if so, but correct me if that's wrong.) Also, what kind of relays are you limited to? (There is quite a variety.)

Comment: start thinking as 4 states, not 3 states ... it's just a 2 bit counter with decoded outputs

Comment: It can be entirely done without semiconductors, only relays, if you want. (In fact, only one type of relay and not two types.) But again, need to know what you are willing to go find in terms of relays, if that's the goal. Otherwise, would need to know what power supplies you have available (other than what the relays require.) Or, if the relays are not required, then what exactly is required in terms of the outputs driving your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you rethink your output pattern as four decoded states of a 2-bit counter, then other approaches come up.  One is to use a CD4017 Johnson counter, since this is combines the count and decode functions in a single chip.

The part has ten decoded outputs, corresponding to BCD counts 0 through 9.  If you diode-OR outputs 0 and 2 together, then this node is A.  Output 1 is B, and output 3 is C.  Output 4 is tied to the chip reset to restart the cycle at A.  Note that all outputs are positive-true, so you will need to invert them with n-channel FETs or NPN transistors to get the open-drain or open collector outputs you describe.

With this approach, you no longer need a relay module with an onboard toggle circuit.  In fact, the FETs can drive a relay coil directly will a protection diode, so you can go with a cheaper bare-bones relay module with nothing but a relay and connectors.

One CD4017 chip

2 1N914 small signal diodes

One pull-down resistor

One decoupling capacitor

One R and one C to debounce the switch input.

Four 2N7000 FETs

Fun thought.  If the circuit power is high enough, like 6 V or more, then the two diodes get replaced by resistors, and the pull-down resistor is eliminated.